# use business objects as source to SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, business-objects

I may be completely off-track, but is it possible to use BO universe as a Source to my SSIS/SSRS.

We've been given a task recently where we've to tap into BO to make SSRS reports. Can we do that?

And if need be can we use that as a source to SSIS for any further transformation.

Also - please help in providing link on how to do it. Google provided me only links where SQL is a source instead of destination.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, if:

- you can *query* the universe using the REST interface (i.e. web service)
- you can consume the OData flow that is returned as the result set

For more information, have a look at [SAP BusinessObjects BI Universe Connector Technical Guide](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-52477).

There are some requirements regarding the version of BusinessObjects and the type of universe you're using:

- SAP BusinessObjects BI 4.1 SP2 or later are supported
- the universe has to be created with the Information Design Tool (i.e. have a .UNX extension)

The current limitations are described in the aforementioned article.

Comment: thank you for the link. I believe we do not fulfil the SP2 requirement. And hence the leaders have to make a call differently.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use Business Objects Universes as a data source in SSIS/SSRS. Universes do not contain data, they are simply an abstraction layer that generates SQL for reporting.

You also cannot link SSRS/SSIS to Business Objects to use universes to generate SQL for downstream use. The links simply do not exist.

Comment: thank you for the response. Even I was thinking on the lines of Data not being there, how will we connect. Cheers